How to assign unique actions to overlapping keycodes (e.g., 0, 00, Delete) in Karabiner-Elements?
I'm turning an old keypad into a macropad using karabiner.
I thought it would be possible because the keyboard 6 is "6" whereas the keypad's is "keypad_6".
I can't figure out how to set the 00 key to do something different than the 0 key (00 seems to have the same keycode as 0 but sends it twice)
also the "delete_or_backspace" is the same code for my keyboard and the keypad.
Is there any way around this ?
